# Transfer image from one ImageButton to another

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-view, imagebutton

I have two ImageButtons, each with a different image within.  I need to find Java code which essentially allows ImageButton2 to display ImageButton1's image.  I've been flailing around, but I think the magic command should be something like this:

```
ImageButton2.setImageResource( ImageButton1.getImageAlpha() );

ImageButton2.setImageResource( ((BitmapDrawable) ImageButton1.getDrawable()).getBitmap() );

int id = ImageButton1.getId();
ImageButton2.setImageResource( R.drawable.(id) );
```

But none of these compile.  The answer has to be something like this:

```
ImageButton2.setImageResource( ImageButton1.getImageResource() );
```

Anyone see the solution?  I've been working on this all day.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be achieved following way:

```
    Drawable drawable = imageButton1.getDrawable();
    Drawable mutatedDrawable = drawable.mutate();
    imageButton2.setImageDrawable(mutatedDrawable);
```

By default, drawables would be shared. If you want changes made one drawable not to affect to the same drawable attached to another view, then you have to explicitly [`mutate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate()) the drawable.